# urllib.urlopen runs only once

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am doing an online course on Coursera and I am stuck for a few ours on one of the assignments. I am not asking anyone to solve it, just... some guidance would be helpful :)

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *

url = raw_input('Enter URL: ')
if len(url) < 1:
    url = "http://pr4e.dr-chuck.com/tsugi/mod/python-data/data/known_by_Fikret.html"
count = int(raw_input('Enter count: '))
pos = int(raw_input('Enter position: ')) - 1
taglist = list()
urllist = list()
urllist.append(url)

print 'Retrieving: ', urllist[0]


for i in range(count):
    html = urllib.urlopen(urllist[-1]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        taglist.append(tag)
    url = taglist[pos].get('href', None)
    print 'Retrieving: ', url
    urllist.append(url)
print 'Last Url: ', urllist[-1]
```

"The program will use urllib to read the HTML from the data files below, extract the href= vaues from the anchor tags, scan for a tag that is in a particular position from the top and follow that link, repeat the process a number of times, and report the last name you find."

The link in the code is just a page with links to other links.

This is the designed output:

```
Enter URL: http: ... /known_by_Fikret.html
Enter count: 4
Enter position: 3
Retrieving: http: ... /known_by_Fikret.html
Retrieving: http: ... /known_by_Montgomery.html
Retrieving: http: ... /known_by_Mhairade.html
Retrieving: http: ... /known_by_Butchi.html
Last Url: http: ... /known_by_Anayah.html
```

The problem I have is that the urllib doesn't run multiple times, only once. I know I am doing something wrong but just can't figure it out :/

Comment: Show us the actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean saying it only runs once, but I'm guessing you're having a problem here:

```
for tag in tags:
    taglist.append(tag)
```

You keep appending to `taglist` every iteration of the loop, keeping everything that was in it already, so after the first iteration, `taglist[pos]` always just points to the same url.

You need to clear `taglist` before you repopulate it, e.g.

```
taglist = list()
for tag in tags:
    taglist.append(tag)
```

Comment: That is it, so simple I just overlooked it. I will keep this in mind on future projects. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Marco was right with clearing your taglist. But still, you won't get the expected result though your code can now run properly. 
Change from:

> url = taglist[pos].get('href', None)

to

> url = taglist[pos-1].get('href', None)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

seems a good approach, i am also taking the same on-line course. instead of appending the taglist, you should initialize it in every iteration so that every "pos" item in the list is a new url required.
here is the modification of the for loop:

```
for i in range(count):
  html = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
  tags = soup('a')
  for tag in tags:
    taglist.append(tag)
  url = taglist[pos].get('href', None)
  print 'Retrieving: ', url
  urllist.append(url)
  taglist = list()
print 'Last Url: ', urllist[-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify with the below:
Tested and worked perfectly for me on python 2.7 and BeautifulSoup4

```
import urllib
from BeautifulSoup import *
taglist=list()
url=raw_input("Enter URL: ")
count=int(raw_input("Enter count:"))
position=int(raw_input("Enter position:"))
for i in range(count):
    print "Retrieving:",url
    html=urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags=soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        taglist.append(tag)
    url = taglist[position-1].get('href', None)
    del taglist[:]
print "Retrieving:",url
```

And in your code clear the taglist after each successful iteration :

```
for i in range(count):
    html = urllib.urlopen(urllist[-1]).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    tags = soup('a')
    for tag in tags:
        taglist.append(tag)
    url = taglist[pos].get('href', None)
    print 'Retrieving: ', url
    urllist.append(url)
    del taglist[:]    \add this line to clear the taglist
```